# Relation between unix-timestamp and ISO time. Why are they unequal?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get timestamp for `January 1, 2018`

```
moment("01-01-2018","MM-DD-YYYY").unix()
```

which from the above statement comes as `1514745000`. But when I try to convert it to `ISOString` as:

```
moment.unix(1514745000).toISOString()
```

it comes down as : `2017-12-31T18:30:00.000Z`

Why is it so? Why isn't it equal to `2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Moment by default uses local time, while [`toISOString`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) output is UTC:

> Note that `.toISOString()` returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode.

If you want to parse `"01-01-2018"` as UTC use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Here an example showing the output difference between parsing in local mode and UTC mode:

```js
// Local 01-01-2018 : 1514761200 (UTC+01:00)
console.log( moment("01-01-2018","MM-DD-YYYY").unix() )
// UTC 01-01-2018: 1514764800
console.log( moment.utc("01-01-2018","MM-DD-YYYY").unix() )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You can find further info in the [Local vs UTC vs Offset](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/) guide.

Comment: So the timestamp generated must also be in UTC?

Comment: I've edited my answer adding a snippet and some links, let me know if it is clearer now.